# Change value in nested list only if a specific number is in that position

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have this bingo board, I also have a random generated list with 10 winning numbers

```
bingo_board = [
        [" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5"],
        [" 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10"],
        ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15"],
        ["16", "17", "18", "19", "20"],
        ["21", "22", "23", "24", "25"]
    ]

#converts bingo nested list to regular list, then randomizes 10 numbers form that list
numbers = [ n for numbers in bingo_board for n in numbers]
    winning_numbers = random.sample(numbers,10)
```

What I want to do is to print the bingo_board again but with the winning numbers highligted with "[  ]" around them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(['['+i+']' if i in winning_numbers else i for i in bingo_board])
```